# Count or Select Backbone View Instances

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view

Let's say I'm trying to create a toDo application, where clicking each toDo opens an edit form for each toDoItem. I only want a maximum of one edit form open at any one time, so right now I am doing this in the edit method of the toDoItem view:

```
edit: function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();    
  if ($('.editForm').length == 0)  {
    //create form model and view
  }
}
```

That works, but doesn't seem very Backbone-y. Is there are way to select or count all instances of a particular view (in this case, the form-view)?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are no utilities method in Backbone.View to count instances of a particular Views. Here are some ideas...

1. Maybe each of your TODO form is tied to a Model? In that case, you can have a model.set/get 'editing' and a collection.isAlreadyEditing() which would filter the models on this field:

   (collection.filter(function(model){ return model.get("editing") }).length > 0

   That would allow you to use on change:editing events throughout your views to control the   logic and have convenient helpers functions in the collection to define some behavior of all those TODO as a whole. This would be one way to implement something closer to a Controller pattern in Backbone.
2. Another common thing in backbone is to keep an array of all the subviews when you instanciate them, so you could just do a:

   _.any(subViews, function(view){return view.editing; })

   Assuming that you keep a editing flag in your subviews when it gets toggled.
3. You can have your views listen to a toggleEdit event with the id or the model or something identifying what is being edited, sometimes the event handler can be as simple as a toggleClass("open", model==this.model)...

I am sure there are millions of other ideas. But counting jQuery selected elements is probably not very high on the list!